# Объединить input и submit в один блок (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

есть идеи как объединить поле ввода и кнопку в один блок как на картинке ? верстка с использованием bootstrap, все должно быть адаптивно[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

```css
.container {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 50px;
}
.container>.row {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.col-sm-5 {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
input[type=email] {
  color: white;
}
input {
  background-color: transparent!important;
  border: 0!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email address">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="submit" value="submit" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```